# Tool for simple discrete event simulations

Tags: simulation

I want to build a simple discrete event simulation similar to the emergency room simulation shown here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6kCMBM-sZs

I have a few different types of people (carpenters, painters, and plumbers).  Each one has to go follow a sequence of steps (buy the wood, polish it), each of which takes a certain amount of time (thirty minutes plus or minus 5 minutes).  And stuff gets 'done' when all three have finished their work.

Is there a free tool that would allow me to simulate this?  The visualization is not as important as the discrete event simulation itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Emergency Room Simulation linked in your question seems to have been produced using [Arena](http://www.arenasimulation.com) from Rockwell Automation (incorporated in the [FactoryTalk](http://www.rockwellautomation.com/rockwellsoftware/products/) suite), which is far from being free (however their might be some special offers for students and academics but I did not look much into it).

You may find a list of discrete event simulation software **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_discrete_event_simulation_software)**, some of them are free and even open-source.

My personal preference goes to **[SimPy](http://simpy.sourceforge.net/)** for being a python module (easy to integrate with a visualization module like vpython, matplotlib or even pygame), being well documented with examples and tutorials, having some plotting capabilities and a programmable GUI.

(Disclaimer: I have some very simple needs in discrete simulation so I did not push the limits of the software I used)

Answer (score 3):

You could simulate that stuff with a queueing simulator.  I happen to have used GPSS as an undergraduate (yes, I'm old).

There's a free GPSS student version for Windows here:
http://www.minutemansoftware.com/downloads/GPSS/World/Student/Setup.msi

GCC can compile [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula).

Comment: 2016: Wolverine has a student version: http://www.wolverinesoftware.com/Downloads.htm  @CarlF not old: seasoned.   GPSS is as fast as any competitor and has survived many decades to enjoy the maturity that few software projects enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the cartoon-like simulation that you want, but there is a mathematical formalism that has been applied to process modeling for manufacturing and other domains: [Petri Nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net). There are software-tools around that can run models based on petri nets and an active community of people that work with them: [link](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/TGI/PetriNets/).

Such a formalism would be useful if you want to determine/compare/explore particular characteristics about the behavior of a system composed of events (like in a factory).

The visual representation, I think, is another problem entirely but if you have "complete" information about the behavior of the system from a simulation, then it should be possible to generate something visual using any tool that is flexible enough, like maybe "[processing](http://processing.org/)" or "[alice](http://www.alice.org/)".